# watir-webdriver: how to retrieve entire line from HTML for which I found substring in it?

Tags: ruby, webdriver, watir-webdriver

I've got something like that in HTML coming from server:

```
<html ...>
<head ...>
....
<link href="http://mydomain.com/Digital_Cameras--~all" rel="canonical" />

<link href="http://mydomain.com/Digital_Cameras--~all/sec_~product_list/sb_~1/pp_~2" rel="next" />
...
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

If b holds the browser object navigated to the page I need to look through, I'm able to find `rel="canonical"` with `b.html.include?` statement, but how could I retrieve the entire line where this substring was found? And I also need the next (not empty) one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a css-locator (or xpath) to get link elements.

The following would return the html (which would be the line) for the link element that has the rel attribute value of "canonical":

```
b.element(:css => 'link[rel="canonical"]').html
#=> <link href="http://mydomain.com/Digital_Cameras--~all" rel="canonical" />
```

I am not sure what you mean by "I also need the next (not empty) one.". If you mean that you want the one with rel attribute value of "next", you can similarly do:

```
b.element(:css => 'link[rel="next"]').html
#=> <link href="http://mydomain.com/Digital_Cameras--~all/sec_~product_list/sb_~1/pp_~2" rel="next" />
```

Comment: +1 for using CSS selectors to get the element and using Watir's html method to get the HTML. Please note, that the html method is not found by default on an Element object in the Ruby Selenium WebDriver bindings.

Comment: @bgoad, while you appear to be right about selenium-webdriver, I am not sure how that applies to this question. As long as watir-webdriver has a method to get the html, is that not all a watir-webdriver user would care about?

Comment: it is helpful information to include, as not all WebDriver Ruby users use the Watir framework (I am one of them!). However, just because a question is a Watir based question, it doesn't mean that users who primarily use the Ruby based SWD bindings will skip the question. There have been numerous times that I have looked at Watir based questions for assistance with an issue that I am looking to address. And I imagine that I am not alone. Plus, its just an additional comment, its not like I edited the response to include that info.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `String#each_line` to iterate through each line in `b.html` and check for `rel=`:

```
b.goto('http://www.iana.org/domains/special')
b.html.each_line {|line| puts line if line.include? "rel="}
```

That should return all strings including `rel=` (although it could return lines that you don't want, such as `<a>` tags with `rel` attributes).

Alternately, you could use [nokogiri](http://www.nokogiri.org/) to parse the HTML:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://www.iana.org/domains/special"))
nodes = doc.css('link')
nodes.each { |node| puts node}
```

Comment: orde: thanks for the idea. For some reason `b.html.each_line` returns each symbol, not each line. What am I doing wrong? So your entire expression returns the whole html file.

Comment: earlyadopter: not sure why it didn't work for you.  I gave it a whirl and got the expected result.  I'll update my answer and include an alternate Nokogiri-based (and probably better) solution.